# CAML query to ignore folders

Tags: list, javascript, caml-query, folder

I am searching my list but the list is in folders. How can I use a query to ignore the folders and get the whole list so I can search it. I am using sharepoint 2013 and javascript.
I want to get all items that are in all folders. None of the folders
I have tried this:

```
        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><QueryOptions><ViewAttributes 
Scope='RecursiveAll' /></QueryOptions><Query><Where><And><IsNotNull>
<FieldRef Name='ID' /></IsNotNull><Eq>
<FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq></And></Where>
</Query></View>");
```

Comment: Are you getting folders as search results? Or you meant to search within a specific folder? Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: I want all items in all of the folders

Comment: `<Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq>` This means you are searching Folder content type items. Thus it will not bring Document content type items. Remove the above `<Eq>` condition and try..

Comment: Nope didn't work

Comment: Try where FSObjType=1?

Comment: put that where?

Comment: @jimmywhizz Add this in your `<Where>`: `<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='int'>0</Value></Eq>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` as the parameter for `getItems()` although simply setting the scope to 'RecursiveAll' and inserting the filter that wjervis suggests should also do the trick.

Example of my proposal:

```
list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
```

You can inspect exactly what this does in your browser dev tools if you're interested:

```
>var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()
undefined
>query.get_viewXml()
"<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
    <Query>
    </Query>
</View>"
```